# Pug Indentation warning in Nuxt project

Tags: nuxt.js, pug

After updating Nuxt, the pug pre-processor start giving a warning in all of the project files.

`unexpected token "indent" (PUG:INVALID_TOKEN) [2,1]`

This is because the pug code starts with one indentation from Template.

```
<template lang="pug">
    h1 Title
</template>
```

This will not show the warning anymore:

```
<template lang="pug">
h1 Title
</template>
```

How can I config Pug so it doesn't show this warning and keep the files with the code indentation?

Thank you for any help.

[image]

Comment: This one is relevant: https://github.com/yyx990803/pug-plain-loader/issues/18

Comment: Unfortunately their solution is to take the indentation off. Thank you for your input.

Comment: What I meant is that there is no solution for this so far. Maybe try to disable the rule if it's an ESlint issue.

Comment: I cannot find if there's a rule enforcing this... Thank you

Comment: Where do you see this error?

Comment: I'm using VSCode. The warning shows up in the Problems tab after I open any Vue file. When I close the file the warning also goes away.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the actual error please (edit your question for this).

Comment: Sure, just edited. Thanks

Comment: I've cleared the node_modules directory and reinstalled the packages and the warning is not showing anymore.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The [@webdiscus/pug-loader](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-plugin) allow using an indent in Vue template:

```html
<template lang="pug">
    h1 Title
</template>
```

Install

```
npm i --save-dev @webdiscus/pug-loader
```

Change your `vue.config.js` according to the following minimal configuration:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,

  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const pugRule = config.module.rule('pug');

    // clear all existing pug loaders
    pugRule.uses.clear();
    pugRule.oneOfs.clear();
  },

  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.pug$/,
          oneOf: [
            // allow import of Pug in JavaScript
            {
              exclude: /\.vue$/,
              loader: '@webdiscus/pug-loader',
              options: {
                method: 'compile', // compile Pug into template function
              },
            },
            // allow <template lang="pug"> in Vue components
            {
              loader: '@webdiscus/pug-loader',
              options: {
                method: 'html', // render Pug into pure HTML string
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: The question is based on Nuxt so the configuration may be a bit different. Still, thanks for the work provided here!